# Display current folder name on Document Library web part

Tags: web-part, document, folder, library, sitepages

I am displaying a Document Libray Web Part (which contains folders) on a subsite homepage.

[image]

When I click on a folder to show its contents, the Document library header still says "Documents". It gives no indication of what folder is being shown. This is confusing, especially when the folder is empty.

[image: Phase 1 Folder actually being shown here]

This is in contrast to how the Documents Library shows when it is opened in its own page:

[image]

How can I make the Document Library Web Part on a Site Page display the current folder name as is done when the Document Library is opened on its own page?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an OOB way, but you can inject a script that create a breadcrumb to enable you to navigate the folder structure.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/RiccardoGDev/sp-breadcrumb
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are using a Modern Document Library, and then you have a Classic List View web part on a classic page.

The classic list view web part does not support breadcrumbs for folder navigation, but the JavaScript snippet at the following link will provide this functionality

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Folder-661709eb

Comment: Thanks. I tried the JavaScript snippet from link provided...but no breadcrumbs were shown. Any other suggestions?

Comment: BTW, is there a way to change my Classic Pages to Modern Pages?

Comment: You may need to modify the script to your needs. Ultimately its not oob functionality and does require custom development. The snippet I provided should be enough to get you started.